# Adding a column which measures time difference between two tasks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add another column which measures the time (in days) for each task from one specific task i.e "sowing".

[Data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBUTR.png)

This code works for single fld_id and taking first row as reference:  #adding a column for : start day of each task wrt to first start date

`df["PastTime"] = df['ssn_start_utc'] - df['ssn_start_utc'][0]`

[Resultant column looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aMBs.png)

**But I have multiple **fld_id** and each have many other tasks, *sowing* among them. I need to add a *Pasttime* column which measures time difference between *sowing* task and other tasks particular to that specific field.**
Desired output:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'ssn_start_utc':pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=6, freq='D'),  'fld_id':[100,100,100,101,101,101], 'task_name': ['sowing','fungicide','insecticide','combine',''combine','sowing'], 'pasttime' :[ 0 days, 1 days, 2 days, 3 days, -1 days, 0 days] })`

I have tried using groupby:

````
df['pasttime'] = df.groupby(['fld_id'])['ssn_start_utc'].transform(

df['ssn_start_utc'] - df.loc[df['name']=='sowing','ssn_start_utc'].values[0]) ```
````

But it shows TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: I want to help, but I am having trouble picturing what your desired output would look like. Could you edit your initial question with more details or add an example of what you want your desired output to look like?